# How can I extract from a heap dump instances allocated from a single thread?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, visualvm, jvisualvm

I have an application with degrading performance.
I have analyzed its behavior using Java VisualVM. I detected a group of threads in a pool that increase their allocated bytes on each execution.
So, I know where the problem is, however I can't find the root of the problem by looking at the code. I would like to look at the objects that these threads are accumulating. Is there a way to do this?
I did a heap dump, but I can't find a way to get only the instances that represent the memory allocated by these threads.

Comment: Have you tried JDK Mission Control?